# get tabulator column Totals value and use in page

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm trying to get a column total value from a tabulator table and be able to use it else where in the page. eg. column "revenue' total = 100.   I want to then be able to use/get the 100 value and use[image] in another box.  I know there is cell.getData but i dont think this works?

Comment: You can get the column calculations using `table.getCalcResults()` http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/column-calcs#results

Comment: does that work on V4.9?  it only seems to methion it in V5.2?

Comment: Yes.  It's the same in v4.9.